# Getting the title of the page and displaying it - JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var lPT = document.title.split(' -')[0];
$('.pageBar .left').text(lPT);
```

With above code snippet, I am trying to display the title of webpage as in below example,

'Home - Sample Website' would come out as 'Home'

The html would be,

```
<div class="pageBar"><div class="left"></div></div>
```

I am trying this, but it is not displaying the title. I am relatively new to JS, and I would like to know, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also, I need to use a div for styling purposes and to fit it into my website

Comment: What you have is fine, provided A) You're including jQuery, and B) Your code is in a script tag **after** the `pageBar` div (and after the jQuery script tag).

Comment: Ah, I was using a service where my scripting was separate from my html, thank you for your help

Comment: Derek - If you've solved whatever the problem was, best to delete this question, as it's just attracting nonsense answers and obvious answers.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this,

```
var lPT = document.title.split('-')[0].trim();
$('.pageBar .left').text(lPT);
```

Also, make use that you are not getting errors in the browser console and you have included the jquery file before this snippet.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that page title contains `-` else it will not show anything.

Check below example:

```js
var lPT = document.title.split(' -')[0];
console.log(lPT);
$('.pageBar .left').text(lPT);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Sarjan - My page</title>
<div class="pageBar"><div class="left"></div></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just like T.J.Crowder said:

1. you need to import jquery
2. you need to place your code after the you want to manipulate with that code (otherwise when your code runs the DOM element with the .pageBar does not exists yet )

Here is an example:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">  
  <title>Home - Sample Website</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="pageBar">
    <div class="left">
      Sample text
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    var lPT = document.title.split(' -')[0];
    $('.pageBar .left').text(lPT);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```